# sqlalchemy- how to save multiple tuples at a time in db and then commit

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this class

```
class Order(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "orders"

id=db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
order_id = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
product_id=db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
quantity=db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)


def save_to_db(self):

    db.session.add_all(self)
    db.session.commit()
```

And i have this class

```
class checkout(Resource):
# @jwt_required
def post(self):
    # current_user = get_jwt_identity()

    # user_wallet=Wallet.find_by_customer_id(current_user)
    order_id=uuid.uuid1()

    data = parser_checkout.parse_args()
    print (data['Products'][0]['Product_id'])
    mainlist=list()
    for i in range(0,len(data['Products'])):
        new_order_prod=Order(
            id=uuid.uuid1(),
            order_id=order_id,
            product_id=data['Products'][i]['Product_id'],
            quantity=data['Products'][i]['quantity']


        )

        mainlist.append(new_order_prod)
    try:

        mainlist.save_to_db()
        return {
            'status':'succes',
            'message':'sucess order placed'
        },200
    except:
        return {
            'status':'error',
            'message':'order placing failed'
        },401
```

I m not getting any error but i found that `mainlist.save_to_db()` is not working i mean that its not going inside the function of that class. Can anyone help me ?
I think its not entering that function becoz class object is tuple with concerned fields but i m making list and calling that so is that why its not working ? Any solution to this?

Comment: `Session.add_all()` expects an iterable, so `db.session.add_all(self)` is not going to work, even if you called `save_to_db()` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `mainlist.save_to_db()` but you declare `mainlist = list()` so it won't have a `save_to_db` method. On top of that, you have a bare `except` so any errors raised by doing that would be suppressed. It's best to only handle specific exceptions, or at least to log what the exceptions is if you're doing a catch-all `except`.

Rather than putting a `save_to_db` method on the `Order` class, which means that calling it only affects 1 instance, call `db.session.add_all(mainlist)` and `db.session.commit()` directly, instead.